# Why {loadposition myposition} of Newsflash modules are not loaded in Intro of a Joomla article?

Tags: module, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-article

Suppose that I define position `special_position_to_be_in_an_article's_intro`.

I put two types (a `Newsflash`, and a `Latest News`) of `module`s in the that position.

I've entered the line `{loadposition special_position_to_be_in_an_article}` in an article's intro.

`Latest News` is shown in the article's intro, but how should I make the `Newsflash` visible too?

Comment: try giving it a different position and possibly one that isn't so long.

Comment: No no no, the real position name is `university_news`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create a second custom module position, for example custom_position2, and then do {loadposition custom_position2} straight after the first one.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't tested it yet, but I will answer if I needed to do that job (because somethings change in my project)